# Regex capture hyperlink

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```js
/(\b(((?<alias>.*)\s*:\s*)){0,1}(?<link>(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]))/ig;
```

Now, I am trying to match the text - **Instructions:http://google.com microsoft: http://microsoft.com**, using the above regex such that **Instructions:http://google.com** should be match 1 and **microsoft: http://microsoft.com** should be match 2.

*Instructions* and *microsoft* should be captured as alias.
But it is not working and matching the entire string Instructions:http://google.com microsoft: http://microsoft.com as match 1.

See sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tc1vbkw2).

Comment: Your regex link is broken, and doesn't link to the actual demo you setup.

Comment: @Tim: I've created a jsfiddle now for testing https://jsfiddle.net/tc1vbkw2/ Please let me know.

Comment: You want to place the URLs into hyperlinks with some label, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the 2 named groups, one option could be

```
\b(?<alias>[^\s:]+):\s*(?<link>(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/\S+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?<alias>[^\s:]+)` Group *alias*
- `:\s*` Match `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(?<link>` Capture group *link*

  - `(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/` Match any of the alternatives and `://`
  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group link

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H4Y1O3/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple here and use `match()` with the following regex pattern:

```regex
\bhttps?:\/\/\S+\b
```

```js
var input = "Instructions:http://google.com microsoft: http://microsoft.com";
var urls = input.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+\b/g, input);
console.log(urls);
```

Note that we use `match()` above in global mode (with the `/g` flag), to match all URLs.

Comment: Hi Tim - this is not the answer. I want to add alias to hyperlink so for example Instructions should be the href's text and http://google.com should be the actual link. That is what I have coded.